# Cannot turn numpy array into a graph in SageMath

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython, sage

After downloading `testnb.sws` following the instructions
on the website
https://sourceforge.net/p/networksym/code/ci/master/tree/
I tried to run it in the legacy "Sage Notebook"
(not the Jupyter notebook), as follows:

- open the Sage Notebook
- click "Upload"
- click "Browse"
- select `testnb.sws`
- click "Upload worksheet"
- click "Evaluate"

---

Evaluating the code cell in this worksheet results in the
following error:

```
ValueError: This input cannot be turned into a graph
```

It seems like in Sage, np.array() is not valid.

However, when I use

```
Aij32 = ([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
```

instead of

```
Aij32 = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
```

it shows

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Turn a numpy array into a graph

If `a` is a numpy array representing an adjacency matrix
for a graph, then instead of

```
Graph(a)
```

one can use

```
Graph(matrix(a))
```

to build the corresponding graph.

#### Fix for the worksheet referred to in the question

In the worksheet `testnb.sws` referred to in the question,
replacing this block

```
# get clusters
print "the orbits are:"
print data32.get_orbits()
```

by the following block

```
def get_orbits(a):
    r"""
    Return the orbits as a list of lists.
    """
    if a._orbits is None:
        a._group, a._orbits = sg.Graph(
                matrix(a.get_adjacency_matrix())
            ).automorphism_group(orbits=True)
    return sg.copy(a._orbits)

# get clusters
print(f"the orbits are:\n{get_orbits(data32)}")
```

makes everything work nicely.